# _NSAutoreleaseNoPool Breaking but No Helpful Stack Trace

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting the message:

> *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3f43660 of class UICFFont
>   autoreleased with no pool in place -
>   just leaking

I have placed a break point using the symbol _NSAutoreleaseNoPool and the program does break, however, the stack trace does not show me any of my code only some UIView and Core Animation layer code.

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100614-fw7u4qtb5bprpwrkh9rdkwn3rq.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100614-fw7u4qtb5bprpwrkh9rdkwn3rq.png)

Is there a better way to get to the bottom of the issue? There is apparently a thread that does not have an auto release pool, but I can't figure out where.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [CATiledLayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) instances ? This is the only type of layer I know that can have their `drawLayer:inContext:` method called from an arbitrary thread:

> As more data is required by the
>   renderer, the layer's
>   drawLayer:inContext: method **is called
>   on one or more background threads** to
>   supply the drawing operations to fill
>   in one tile of data. The clip bounds
>   and CTM of the drawing context can be
>   used to determine the bounds and
>   resolution of the tile being
>   requested.

Comment: Yes. I am using CATiledLayer.

Comment: So you must avoid using UI controls inside your layers; they don't like being called on a thread other than the UI thread. It is only safe to use Quartz2D functions (CGContextXXX, etc).

If you really need to display UI controls, do it in a view.

Comment: You can't use any UIKit (or very few) classes inside the drawLayer:inContext: method. You'll need to use CG equivalents in order to use CATiledLayer.

Comment: The only UIKit class I am using is a UIImage. I'm calling [image drawInRect:] on it inside of drawLayer:inContext:. What's the alternative? Do I need to create the image outside of the drawLayer:inContext: and then simply call drawInRect in there?

Comment: If you have an UIImage, then a solution is to use CGContextDrawImage like this: CGContextDrawImage(ctx, rect, image.CGImage);